# Make only 1 column distinct in SQL?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to make one column distinct? I have a query that takes the first two columns and sums them together for the third column. In row 2 we have 2+1=3; then in row 4 we have 1+2=3. Is there a way to put a restriction/constraint on my statement so that I can eliminate those rows?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT TableA.n AS ColumnA, TableB.n AS ColumnB, (TableA.n + TableB.n) as [Sum]
FROM MyTable AS TableA CROSS JOIN MyTable AS TableB
WHERE TableA.n <= 3 AND TableB.n <= 3
```

I thought perhaps I could do this but it doesn't work: `distinct (TableA.n + TableB.n) as [Sum]`

[image]

Using Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can require that `columnA < columnB`:

```
SELECT TableA.n AS ColumnA, TableB.n AS ColumnB, (TableA.n + TableB.n) as [Sum]
FROM MyTable AS TableA CROSS JOIN
      MyTable AS TableB
WHERE TableA.n < TableB.n AND
      TableA.n <= 3 AND TableB.n <= 3 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @GordonLinoff - this does requirement works great on my example. Thank you.

Comment: My example query is my 'simplified' version of what I'm working on - is there any other way of doing this? One of my requirements is that the value in the third column can only be shown once. - that is why I thought i should use a distinct

Comment: @user3281388 . . . Perhaps you should ask another question that does a better job of explaining what you really need.  This appears to be the answer to this question.